# Configure JCache implementation in Spring

Tags: spring, ehcache, jcache

Looking at the Ehcahce implementation of net.sf.cache.JS107, I am trying to achieve the following code snippet to produce the JCache implementation as a Spring managed bean..

```
  Ehcache Ehcache = new net.sf.ehcache.Cache(...);
  net.sf.jsr107cache.Cache cache = new JCache(ehcache);
  manager.addJCache(cache);
```

Here is my manager bean:

```
   <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

Here is my Ehcache bean:

```
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
        <property name="diskPersistent" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Here is how I create my JCache bean:

```
<bean id="jcache" class="net.sf.jsr107cache.Cache">
        <constructor-arg ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>
```

What I want is to be able to invoke the following method in Spring to apply my JCache to the Ehcache manager:

```
manager.addJCache(cache);
```

There must be a way to do this in Spring?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with XML, just use Java `@Configuration`:

```
@Bean
public Ehcache ehcache() {
    return new net.sf.ehcache.Cache(...);
}

@Bean
public net.sf.jsr107cache.Cache jsrCache() {
    net.sf.jsr107cache.Cache cache = new JCache(ehcache());
    manager.addJCache(cache);
    return cache;
}
```